# How to redirect to base url which is not always unique

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url

Right now in my test environment it's sufficient to say `window.location.href = "/home"`but in other environment this base url will not be the same.

How do I, using JavaScript, redirect the page to the base url of the web application?

It's an ASP NET MVC Application.

Comment: What is 'base url' of the web application?

Comment: Locally it's: https://localhost/jkip. On a test server environment it's https://testt1.jkip.com/, and in production similar to the test environment i.e. nothing after the forward slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the base url with `@Url.Content("~/");` thus you have access to the value. How you share it with javascript is up to you.  One way is to simply put the value in your site layout(s):

_layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      applicationRootUrl = @UrlContent("~/");

...
```

then in any subsequent javascript

```
window.location.href = applicationRootUrl;
```

Comment: The value was already in a <base> tag in the _Layout.cshtml file, which gets the value from the web.config. I'm able to just retrieve the value of the <base> tag and it works! thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

This is actually not possible to autodetect. You can define a variable in your script, eg.

```
var baseurl='/jkip';
```

and then do your redirects as

```
window.location.href=baseurl;
```

You will need to change the variable accordingly on localhost (set value '/jkip') and on production environment (set value to '/').

Alternatively you may need to redirect to 'current directory', which can be done without defining any variables at all, simply as

```
window.location.href='.';
```

but I'm unsure if this is what you want.

Comment: Ouch, I've overlooked you're on ASP. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your input regardless :)